# PHP Simple Dom Parser Blank Array

Tags: php, linux, parsing, dom, web-scraping

I'm trying to use the Simple Dom Parser to extract a piece of html from Yahoo Sports..

```
<?php

 include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/5763');

$ret = $html->find('ul[class=keystats]');

print $ret;

?>
```

Basically i'm trying to get the Win-Loss record and ERA from the following

```
<ul class="keystats">            <li><strong>W-L</strong> 3-1</li>
        <li><strong>ERA</strong> 3.62</li>
        <li><strong>K</strong> 23</li>
        <li><strong>Walks</strong> 1</li>
        <li><strong>WHIP</strong> 1.04</li>
      </ul>
```

Its returning just "Array" when i use the code shown above, any ideas?

Comment: Well.. that gave me something but..

`Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => ul [attr] => Array ( [class] => keystats ) [children] => Array` its a bunch of gibberish, 20,000+ characters worth that wouldnt fit on the page

Comment: http://www.yourisk.com/php/get_era.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this brings anything?

```
$ret = $html->find("ul[class=keystats] li:first-child",0)->plaintext;
echo $ret;
```

you can also try this:

```
$ret = strip_tags($html->find("ul[class=keystats] li:first-child",0)->innertext);
echo $ret;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/5763');

$html->find("ul[class=keystats] li strong",0)->outertext = "";
$wl = $html->find("ul[class=keystats] li",0)->innertext;
echo $wl;

$html->find("ul[class=keystats] li strong",1)->outertext = "";
$era = $html->find("ul[class=keystats] li",1)->innertext;
echo $era;
```

Comment: Both produced blank pages for me

Comment: check my updated version. The trick is to first remove the `<strong>` tag and then read in the text. `->plaintext` will work also.